# Get child name in Firebase

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

[My database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl2uB.png)

I want to get child name

Coffee
Latte
Tea
Ade

How can I get these?

Answer (score 1):

You probably looking for this documentation [Work with List of Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events)

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('Menu/Drink');
ref.once('value', (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    var drinkName = childSnapshot.key; // <- this is your Name
    var drinkValue = childSnapshot.val();
  });
});
```

Real-time database always uses key-value objects (even when you create Array it will use 0,1...n number as key). So you can get any object as a collection and iterate through snapshots like items.